# How to get JSON from one parameter of request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, infyom

I want to send a stringified JSON to one of the fields of an API request like following:

Decoded:

```
https://api.some.com/foo/bar?a=788&b=My Name&c=[{"name":"pejman"},{"Some":"thing"}]
```

I want to get `c` parameter using `$request->c` but I want to get it as a decoded JSON automatically in my controller.

This is my PHP code

**MyRequest.php**:

```php
<?php

use InfyOm\Generator\Request\APIRequest;

class MyRequest extends APIRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'a' => 'required',
            'b' => 'required',
            'c' => 'requried',
        ];
    }
}
```

**SomeController.php**:

```php
<?php

class SomeController extends Controller
{

    public function store(MyRequest $request)
    {
        $c = $request->c;
        $c = $request->json('c');
        $c = $request->json()->all();
    }

}
```

> **I want `$c` to be a JSON decoded automatically in my controller, How can I do that? Is that event possible to do this using `MyReqest` and how?**

Comment: Add a public method to your `MyRequest` that gets `c` decoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the request data using `prepareForValidation()` method that located in `Illuminate\Validation\ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait`. So, implement this method in your `MyRequest` class:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'c' => json_decode($this->c),
    ]);
}
```